# How to use correctly UpdatePanel inside a Listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I've been breaking up my head with an issue, yet I don't seem to find an adequate solution to my problem. I have the following piece of code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListView ID="productList" OnItemDataBound="pharmaciesList_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="span1"  ID="Units" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Units_TextChanged" />
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Discount" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Units" EventName="TextChanged" />
     </Triggers>
    </asp:ListView>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        productList.DataSource = this.LineItems;
        DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Unidades_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox qtt = (TextBox)sender;
    var parent = qtt.Parent;
    while (!(parent is IDataItemContainer))
        parent = parent.Parent;

    ListViewDataItem listitem = parent as ListViewDataItem;

    Literal lit = listitem.FindControl("Descuento") as Literal;
    lit.Text = "A";
}
```

Every item contains a textbox with units and a literal that should be updated with a new discount depending on the amount entered (for the purposes of testing, I just want this label to change to "A" for the time being). Even though, after stepping with the debugger, lit.Text = "A" is executed after I change a Textbox in that list, the literal is not being updated.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to update it correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for previous code as i assumed the ListView to be Listbox. Actucally it will never be able to find the Textbox inside the Listview.

Though one thing is for sure you need to write `<trigger>` outside the `<ContentTemplate>`.

Any Particular reason you are using Listview. If you can use Listbox/Grid?

Comment: Your approach raises an exception: A control with ID 'Units' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel'.

Comment: The use of ListView was up to another frontend developer, but is there any special difference on using Grid instead of ListView if ListView has the looks we wanted for the Page?

Comment: Actually using Gridview will allow us to find the Textbox control inside the Content template which Listview don't allow(resulting into error). This happend when you used my code. But if you use Gridview it will not give you error. Try using Gridview rather Listview and you will see the difference.